# Working with Offsets in C#

Tags: offset

### Heading

Hello,

how can i convert this string:

```
string test = "0x17D";
```

to a int.

I need this to specify the position in a Hex-Document.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.Position = Convert.ToInt64(test); //doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs.Position = Convert.ToInt64(test, 16);
```